# Can't find table 0

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, ms-access

The code works great on other tables.
The code return true if he found on the table the thing he get and false he hi did not find it.
Error Translation: cant find table 0

```
        public bool Found(long num)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string str = string.Format("select * from Customers where Customer_Id={0} ", num);
        ds = ReturnDS(str);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

        public DataSet ReturnDS(string SqlStr)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        try
        {
            //  sql מאפיין אשר מאפשר לקבוע או לקבל את הוראת :CommandText
            cmd.CommandText = SqlStr;
            //  OleDbConnection מאפיין אשר מאפשר לקבוע או לקבל את אובייקט ההתחברות מהמחלקה :Connection
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            //DataSet ומשימה שנייה בכדי לעדכן את בסיס הנתונים בהתאם למידע שהתרחש ב  DataSet יצירת מופע למחלקה המייצגת אובייקט ההתחברות לבסיס הנתונים. ייצוג זה דרוש לשתי משימות משימה ראשונה בכדי להעביר נתונים מבסיס הנתונים ל 
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

            // DataSet טוענת את הנתונים לתוך אובייקט  Fill המתודה 
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { MessageBox.Show(e.Message); }
        finally
        {
            cnn.Close();
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

[image: The Error&Code]

Comment: Show us `ReturnDS()`

Comment: Using `select count(*) from Customers where Customer_Id={0}` will be much faster.

Comment: There is no table named _Customers_ in your database. The interesting point is: Why your ReturnDS doesn't throw an exception and stop the code execution immediately? It seems a bigger problem here.

Answer (score 0):

The error means, that your DataSet don't contains a Table with the Index 0.
Check what ReturnDS is doing and if there are some information's, why it can't find a table. Maybe you just have an error in your SQL statement.

Does the table exist? Does the table contain a column with the name `Customer_Id`? Do you have read rights? etc.

Comment: Yes I have all of this

Comment: And the catch doesn't get triggered in your `ReturnDS` ?

Comment: @GalBen Ok. In ReturnDS you see a Try{}catch (Exception e){} which catches an exception. You should see a message box, which shows the cached exception. With try catch you can prevent, that your code crashes like in your screenshot. Do you see any message box, when you execute `ReturnDS` ?

Comment: Yes data type mismatch

Comment: Then the where criteria don't match with the column datatype. Please check in your Database, which type the column have. Maybe it's just a number. You could quick try to replace the `{0}`in your `WHERE` with `0` without parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the tables count too.

```
public bool Found(long num)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string str = string.Format("select * from Customers where Customer_Id={0} ", num);
    ds = ReturnDS(str);
    return ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0;
}
```

Comment: This would return an error as well. You still try to access the table with index 0.

Comment: It won't if the .Tables.Count > 0

Comment: I will check it

Comment: @EugeneKomisarenko And what happend, if `.Tables.Count == 0` ?

Comment: It will return false like expected. Conditional expression are not evaluated all at once in C#, it is happening one by one from left to right hence no error will be triggered since the second conditional will not be executed.

Comment: It says data mismatch

Comment: Post the exception details to have a look

Comment: @EugeneKomisarenko I would not have thought. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: How do I do this. It just opens messagebox and says that nothing else

Comment: Put break point inside catch block, run your code, wait for break point to be hit, right click on `e` variable and do quick watch, it will give you more information on what is going on.